# What are zygo/meta/histo/para/futu/dyna/whatever-morphisms?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinators, category-theory

Is there a list of them with examples accessible to a person without extensive category theory knowledge?

Comment: Why do you want to know them? (If you're not interested in category theory, I mean...)

Comment: Category theory knocks me on my ass every time.

Comment: Zygo-Meta-Histo-Para-Expi-Ali-Docious!

Comment: 2ShreevatsR: Just out of curiosity. Saw them mentioned in some articles on Haskell.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Functional Programming with Bananas, Lenses, Envelopes and Barbed Wire(PDF)](http://eprints.eemcs.utwente.nl/7281/01/db-utwente-40501F46.pdf) should help as well. The notation will get a bit hairy, but reading it a few times you should be able to knock down that list of yours.

Also, take a look at the recursion schemes [(archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140713010615/http://comonad.com/reader/2009/recursion-schemes/) [blog post](http://comonad.com/reader/2009/recursion-schemes/), the blogger plans on presenting each individually soon, so check back to it regularly --I guess.

Comment: Thank you, the paramorphism description there helped.

Comment: The author of that blog post told me a day or two ago that he was aware his blog is currently down but that he is traveling and won't be able to do anything about it for another week.

Comment: ahh, it was down a while ago too for some time. I had actually (at this point) figured he took it off-line. thanks

Answer (score 11):

Edward Kmett recently posted a [Field Guide to recursion schemes](http://comonad.com/reader/2009/recursion-schemes/), perhaps it helps?

Comment: Happy to help. Your best bet might be to start from, say, the dynamorphism paper by Vene and Kabanov. Since it motivates at least the use of histo and dyna and from there you can figure out futu.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.60.9336

Answer (score 10):

Start with learning about catamorphisms; those are the easiest to grasp. You already know one: `foldr`!

Then go for anamorphisms (`unfoldr`) and paramorphisms. Only then go for the other Wikipedia articles/papers; by then they will be easier to understand.

Comment: I've already grasped cata, ana, hylo and meta, that's why I didn't mentioned them in question. :) For the rest wikipedia articles are not very extensive or don't exist.

Answer (score 7):

Check out Tim Williams' slide on recursion schemes here:

http://www.timphilipwilliams.com/slides.html

They explain all of the *-morphisms with motivating examples of each.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a start: [Wikipedia "Recursion schemes" category.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Recursion_schemes)