# A library implementation of a recursion scheme

Tags: haskell, recursion, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

I 'invented' a recursion scheme which is a generalization of catamorphism. When you fold a data structure with catamorphism you don't have access to subterms, only to subresults of folding:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
import qualified Data.Map as M

newtype Fix f = Fix { unFix :: f (Fix f) }

cata :: Functor f => (f b -> b) -> Fix f -> b
cata phi = self where
    self = phi . fmap (\x -> self x) . unFix
```

The folding function `phi` has only access to the result of `self x`, but not to original `x`. So I added a joining function:

```
cataWithSubterm :: Functor f => (Fix f -> c -> b) -> (f b -> c) -> Fix f -> c
cataWithSubterm join phi = self
    where self = phi . fmap (\x -> join x (self x)) . unFix
```

Now it's possible to combine `x` and `self x` in a meaningful way, for example using `(,)`:

```
data ExampleFunctor a = Var String | Application a a deriving Functor

type Subterm = Fix ExampleFunctor

type Result = M.Map String [Subterm]

varArgs :: ExampleFunctor (Subterm, Result) -> Result
varArgs a = case a of
    Var _ -> M.empty
    Application ((Fix (Var var)), _) (arg, m) -> M.insertWith (++) var [arg] m

processTerm :: (ExampleFunctor (Subterm, Result) -> Result) -> Subterm -> Result
processTerm phi term = cataWithSubterm (,) phi term
```

`processTerm varArgs` returns for each identifier the list of actual arguments it receives on different control paths. E.g. for `bar (foo 2) (foo 5)` it returns `fromList [("foo", [2, 5])]`

Note that in this example results are combined uniformly with other results, so I expect existence of a simpler implementation using a derived instance of `Data.Foldable`. But in general it's not the case as `phi` can apply its knowledge of internal structure of `ExampleFunctor` to combine 'subterms' and 'subresults' in ways not possible with Foldable.

My question is: can I build `processTerm` using stock functions from a modern recursion schemes library such as `recursion-schemes/Data.Functor.Foldable`?

Comment: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317242/what-are-paramorphisms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Folding such that it "eats the argument and keeps it too" is called a [paramorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paramorphism). Indeed, your function can be readily expressed using [*recursion-schemes*](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/recursion-schemes/3.0.0.2/doc/html/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) as

```
cataWithSubterm :: Functor f => (Fix f -> b -> a) -> (f a -> b) -> Fix f -> b
cataWithSubterm f g = para $ g . fmap (uncurry f)
```

Moreover, if we supply `(,)` to `cataWithSubterm` as you did in `processTerm`, we get

```
cataWithSubterm (,)  :: Functor f => (f (Fix f, b) -> b) -> Fix f -> b
```

which is precisely `para` specialized for `Fix`:

```
para                 :: Functor f => (f (Fix f, b) -> b) -> Fix f -> b
```