# Building a BST from a depth-first preorder list in Haskell more idiomatically

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

[This submission to Programming Praxis](http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/10/18/binary-tree-traversal/#comment-9262) gives an O(n) function that "undoes" a preorder traversal of a binary search tree, converting a list back into a tree. Supplying the missing data declaration:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch {value::a, left::Tree a, right:: Tree a}
                 deriving (Eq, Show)

fromPreOrder :: Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
fromPreOrder [] = Leaf
fromPreOrder (a:as) = Branch a l (fromPreOrder bs)
  where
    (l,bs) = lessThan a as

lessThan n [] = (Leaf,[])
lessThan n all@(a:as)
  | a >= n    = (Leaf,all)
  | otherwise = (Branch a l r,cs)
  where (l,bs) = lessThan a as
        (r,cs) = lessThan n bs
```

It's obvious that one constructor is added to the tree in each recursive step, which is key to its efficiency.

The only "problem" is that the list is threaded through the computation manually, which is not a terribly Haskellian way to do it and makes it a little harder to see that it is actually consumed element by element in a single-threaded manner.

I attempted to correct this using a state monad ([prettified on Codepad](http://codepad.org/gdr5IMUW)):

```
import Control.Monad.State

data Tree a = Leaf
            | Branch {root::a, left::Tree a, right::Tree a}
               deriving (Eq,Show)

peek = State peek' where
  peek' [] = (Nothing,[])
  peek' a@(x:_) = (Just x,a)
 
pop = State pop' where
  pop' [] = error "Tried to read past the end of the list"
  pop' (_:xs) = ((),xs)

prebuild'::Ord a => State [a] (Tree a)
prebuild' = do
  next <- peek
  case next of
    Nothing -> return Leaf
    Just x -> do
                 pop
                 leftpart <- lessThan x
                 rightpart <- prebuild'
                 return (Branch x leftpart rightpart) 

lessThan n = do
  next <- peek
  case next of
    Nothing -> return Leaf
    Just x -> do
      if x < n
      then do
         pop
         leftpart <- lessThan x
         rightpart <- lessThan n
         return (Branch x leftpart rightpart)
      else
         return Leaf

prebuild::Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
prebuild = evalState prebuild'
```

Unfortunately, this just looks obscenely messy, and doesn't seem any easier to reason about.

One thought I haven't been able to get anywhere with yet (in part because I don't have a deep enough understanding of the underlying concepts, quite likely): could I use a left fold over the list that builds a *continuation* that ultimately produces the tree? Would that be possible? Also, would it be anything short of insane?

Another thought was to write this as a tree unfold, but I don't think it's possible to do that efficiently; the list will end up being traversed too many times and the program will be O(n^2).

#### Edit

Taking things from another direction, I have the nagging suspicion that it might be possible to come up with an algorithm that starts by splitting up the list into increasing segments and decreasing segments, but I haven't yet found something concrete to do with that idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem you're having with `State` is that your primitives (`push`, `pop`, `peek`) are not the right ones. I think a better one would be something like `available_`, which checks if the front of the stack matches a particular condition, and executes something different in each case:

```
available_ p f m = do
    s <- get
    case s of
        x:xs | p x -> put xs >> f x
        _ -> m
```

Actually, in our use case, we can specialize a bit: we will always want to return a `Leaf` when the head of our stack doesn't satisfy the condition, and we'll always want to recurse when it does.

```
available p m = available_ p
    (\x -> liftM2 (Branch x) (lessThan' x) m)
    (return Leaf)
```

(You could also just write `available` to begin with and skip `available_` entirely. In my first iteration, that is what I did.) Now writing `fromPreOrder` and `lessThan` are a snap, and also I think give some insight into their behavior. I'll name them with primes so we can double-check they do the right thing with QuickCheck.

```
fromPreOrder' = available (const True) fromPreOrder'
lessThan' n   = available (<n)         (lessThan' n)
```

And in ghci:

```
> quickCheck (\xs -> fromPreOrder (xs :: [Int]) == evalState fromPreOrder' xs)
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Comment: I like this a lot. I think it's a pretty elegant way to show what's going on in this particular algorithm. If I were writing it as a one-off I'd use this. If I knew I was going to be doing more work on the tree I'd go for the effect stack I built in my answer.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Yeah, I'm not sure whether this is the right approach for scaling up or not! Then again I'm not sure what "scaling up" would necessarily mean for this.

Comment: I really like the `(<n)` vs `const True` approach to making things uniform. That's definitely my favorite part of this answer.

Comment: This looks really neat. The thing I like least is that the two recursive invocations of `lessThan'` that were previously clearly closely related are now completely separated, one inside the common combinator and one in its argument.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam, that is a significant problem indeed.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam If that is an aesthetic you prefer, you can easily inline the definition of `available` at its two call sites. Then all three (not two!) recursive calls are again clearly related, at the cost of some repetition.

Comment: @DanielWagner, I think that may be best. `available_`, or a slight variation thereof, is a much more pleasant function than `available` is--it's pretty hard to describe clearly what `available` really does.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't answer the question about continuation passing, I believe that the `State` monad based implementation can be written much more clearly. First, we can use notational convenience such as those from `Control.Applicative` to make it easier to read. Second, we can upgrade the effect stack to include `Maybe` in order to capture the notion of failure (a) from taking the head of an empty list and (b) from the `(a >= n)` comparison as an effect.

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Applicative
```

The final code uses the backtracking-state monad transformer stack. This means that we wrap `State` around `Maybe` instead of `Maybe` around `State`. In some sense we can think of this as meaning that failure is the "primary" effect. In practice it means that if the algorithm fails there's no way to continue using potentially bad state and so it must backtrack to the last known good state.

```
type Preord a b = StateT [a] Maybe b
```

Since we keep taking the head of a list and want to capture that failure correctly, we'll use a "safe head" function (which is the natural destructor of a list anyway, despite not being in the base Haskell libraries)

```
-- Safe list destructor
uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])
uncons []     = Nothing
uncons (a:as) = Just (a, as)
```

If we look at it cleverly we'll notice that this is already *exactly* the form of our monadic computation (`StateT [a] Maybe b` is isomorphic to `[a] -> Maybe (b, [a])`). We'll give it a more evocative name when lifted into the `Monad`.

```
-- Try to get the head or fail
getHead :: Preord a a
getHead = StateT uncons
```

A common feature of this algorithm is stopping local failures by providing a default value. I'll capture this in the `certain` combinator

```
-- Provides a default value for a failing computation     
certain :: b -> Preord a b -> Preord a b
certain def p = p <|> return def
```

And now we can write the final algorithm very cleanly in our `Preord` monad.

```
fromPreOrder :: Ord a => Preord a (Tree a)
fromPreOrder = certain Leaf $ do
  a <- getHead
  Branch a <$> lessThan a <*> fromPreOrder

lessThan :: Ord a => a -> Preord a (Tree a)
lessThan n = certain Leaf $ do
  a <- getHead
  guard (a < n)
  Branch a <$> lessThan a <*> lessThan n
```

Note that `Applicative` style helps to indicate that we're building the components of the `Branch` constructor using further effectful (state consuming) computations. The `guard` short-circuits `lessThan` when the pivot is already the least element in the pre-order traversal. We also explicitly see how both `fromPreOrder` and `lessThan` default out to `Leaf` when they cannot compute a better result.

(Also note that `fromPreOrder` and `lessThan` are nearly identical now, a commonality Daniel Wagner exploited in his own answer when writing `available`.)

We finally would want to hide all the monadic noise since, to an outside user, this is just a pure algorithm.

```
rebuildTree :: [a] -> Tree a
rebuildTree = fromMaybe Leaf . runStateT fromPreOrder
```

---

For a complete picture, here's the implementation of the algorithm using only the `State` monad. Note all the extra noise for handling failure! We've absorbed the entire `popElse` function into the effects of the backtracking state monad. We also lift the `if` up into the failure effect. Without that effect stack, our combinators are terrifically specific to the application instead of decomplected and useful elsewhere.

```
-- Try to take the head of the state list and return the default
-- if that's not possible.
popElse :: b -> (a -> State [a] b) -> State [a] b
popElse def go = do
  x <- get
  case x of
    []     -> return def
    (a:as) -> put as >> go a

push :: a -> State [a] ()
push a = modify (a:)

fromPreOrder :: Ord a => State [a] (Tree a)
fromPreOrder = popElse Leaf $ \a -> Branch a <$> lessThan a <*> fromPreOrder

lessThan :: Ord a => a -> State [a] (Tree a)
lessThan n = 
  popElse Leaf $ \a ->
    if a >= n
    then push a >> return Leaf
    else Branch a <$> lessThan a <*> lessThan n
```

Comment: I don't yet understand monad transformers at all, unfortunately. I'm thinking about working through "Learn You a Haskell" but I haven't yet.

Comment: The (vague) concept of continuation passing is that this algorithm can be seen as optimizing the naive "insert elements into the BST one at a time" by descending down into the tree while building and only ascending as required. We're traveling through the tree essentially in pre-order filling in gaps as we go.

Comment: Monad transformers are a way to combine the effects provided by two different monads. For instance, in my second example I use the notion of failure from `Maybe` in order to lift failures like trying to access the head of `[]` or when the head of the `lessThan` state is greater than the pivot value directly into the effect layer. The end result is we get to think of threads of stateful computations which unwind upon failure and have a global notion of defaulting.

Comment: There's something a bit dissatisfying about using `StateT [a] Maybe`. Since you use `certain Leaf` at the front of all the computations of interest, we know that the computation will hand us a `Just` at the end; but this is not really reflected in the type system.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. In a larger algorithm I'd want to think about writing `certain` like `certain :: Monad m => b -> MaybeT m b -> m b`, but that sacrifices the backtracking immediately. It's also a lot of noise for such a small algorithm.

Comment: I haven't read through all the changes yet, but I'm a bit concerned about the "backtracking" aspect. Specifically, I set up the peek/pop rather than a pop/push because I want it to be very clear that we never push something on that we didn't pop off immediately before. Once we've taken two elements off, the first never goes back on.

Comment: As Daniel Wagner points out in an earlier comment, the backtracking that occurs here is extremely local. We never pop more than one element; which we can verify by noting that at most one `getHead` occurs between calls to `certain`.

Comment: Isn't your comparison operator backwards? Don't we want to fail if what we popped off is too *big*?

Comment: You are correct. I was translating from the original `lessThan n all@(a:as) | a >= n = (Leaf,all)` but forgot to flip the conditional when applying `guard`. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, the state monad doesn't really improve the situation, and I don't think it can be expected to, as it's both much too general in that it allows arbitrary access to the state, and annoying in that it enforces unnecessary sequencing.

At first glance, this looks quite like a `foldr` : we do one thing for the empty case, and in the `(:)` case we take the head off and make a recursive call based on the tail. However, as the recursive call isn't just using the tail directly, it isn't quite a `foldr`.

We could express it as a [paramorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317242/what-are-paramorphisms) but I don't think that really adds anything to the readability.

What I did notice is that the complicated recursion on the tail is all based on `lessThan`, which led me to the following idea for breaking down the algorithm:

```
lessThans [] = []
lessThans (a:as) = (a, l) : lessThans bs
   where (l, bs) = lessThan a as

fromPreOrder2 :: Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
fromPreOrder2 = foldr (\(a, l) r -> Branch a l r) Leaf . lessThans
```

I'm sure `lessThans` could have a better name but I'm not quite sure what!

The `foldr` can also be expressed as `foldr (uncurry Branch) Leaf` but I'm not sure if that's an improvement.

EDIT: also, `lessThans` is an [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr), leading to this version:

```
fromPreOrder3 :: Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
fromPreOrder3 = foldr (uncurry Branch) Leaf . unfoldr lessThanList

lessThanList [] = Nothing
lessThanList (a:as) = Just ((a, l), bs)
    where (l, bs) = lessThan a as
```

Comment: Some of the sequencing is necessary: nothing whatsoever can be done on the right until the left is finished, and one of the few things I like about my approach is that this is explicit. Unfortunately, my approach obscures the fact that the construction is "right lazy" in that traversing the resulting tree in preorder uses up the input list one element at a time. I believe J. Abrahamson's use of Applicative (which I don't understand yet) is intended to ameliorate that weakness.