# Map over list, except for last list element

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, map-function

How do I best map over all elements of a list, except for the last list element?

Say we have a list `let l = [1,2,3,4]` and want to get `[2,3,4,4]`.

I do have a solution, but it doesn't feel like the "functional" way to do it (in ghci):

```
let l = [1,2,3,4]
let len = toIntegral $ length l -- to avoid a type mismatch Integer <-> Int
let l1 = zip l [1..]
let l2 = map (\(x,y) -> if y < len then (x + 1,y) else (x,y)) l1
let l3 = map (fst) l2
```

Not very nice...I do hope there is a better way! Since I'm a novice in functional programming, I don't know where to start looking for it though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just re-write `map` but make a special case when there's only one element:

```
mapBut1 :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapBut1 f [] = []
mapBut1 f [x] = [x]
mapBut1 f (x:xs) = f x : mapBut1 f xs
```

This will now work even for infinite lists, it's a lot faster than calculating the length, and makes it more readable.  Note that this does restrict your function to be of type `a -> a` instead of `a -> b`.

Alternatively, you could do

```
mapBut1 f (x:y:xs) = f x : mapBut1 f (y:xs)
mapBut1 f other = other
```

They're equivalent definitions, but the latter uses 1 fewer pattern matches.  I would prefer the former, though, since it's more immediately obvious what cases are being handled.

Comment: Very nice! Just one minor thing: shouldn't the `xs` in the very last line of your code be an `x`, since we are matching a list of length 1?

Comment: @mort firstly, Haskell doesn't care what we name the variables, so renaming `xs` to `x` won't change the meaning of the code.  Secondly, that line is matching anything that didn't match the pattern `(x:xs)`, which could be `[_]` or `[]` (`[_]` indicates a list of one element).  So what it's saying is that anything other than the pattern `(x:xs)` would be matched, not that a single element would be.  However, you did make me spot a small bug I have in this code.

Answer (score 10):

This is a job for pretend-paramorphism, as usual:

```
import Data.List (tails)

mapButLast :: (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
mapButLast f = foldr g [] . tails where
  g (x:_:_) r = f x : r
  g xs      _ = xs
```

Or with proper [`para`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317563/849891) we'd just write

```
mapButLast f = para g [] where
  g x [] r = [x]
  g x _  r = f x : r
```

where

```
para f z (x:xs) = f x xs (para f z xs)
para f z []     = z
```

Comment: That's a nice pattern!

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I've edited some more in, with a link. ;)

Comment: `para` is the "obvious" way, but I like the idea of using `tails` to get a pretend-para. Though, with them both side by side I'm less certain it's actually that much *more* intelligible than `para` itself.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson ultimately they are the same - access to `tails` is what `para` does (up to one skipped beat). with `tails` it even gets to reuse structure. Sometimes the non-standard `para f z [] = z; para f z xs@(x:t) = f x xs (para f z t)` might be preferable, and that's exactly the `foldr ... tails` variant.

Comment: oh, and [nothing is new under the sun](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#maplist).

Comment: Yep, agreed. I'd just not seen it written out in this form before.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`init` and `last`](http://lyah.haskell.fr/img/listmonster.png) from standard librairies (no special import) **if you don't care about performances**.

#### you can write

```
map f (init list) ++ [last list]
```

#### where

- *`f`* : function you want to map
- *`list`* : list you want to map over

Comment: This is not *that* bad performance-wise as `init` is lazy and `last list` expr. is in WHNF before evaluated. I'd bet it's on par with the accepted answer by O(n) traversing to the last elem which may be well optimized by ghc.

Comment: @DavidUnric, this has pretty bad performance characteristics.  In particular, it is not a good streamer: it will keep the whole input list in memory until the last element is evaluated.

Comment: I like this solution because it's readable even for beginners ;)

Answer (score 1):

What makes this last element so special?

I know it does not answer your question, but I'd consider a type like

```
data Foo a = Foo a [a]
```

and an appropriate Functor.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add an alternative using list comprehension and an attempt to compare the solutions (first time I try it so let me know if I didn't do it right)

```
reverse $ last l : [f x | x <- tail (reverse l)]
```

It is slower than most of the other solutions (see report link below).

Here is a sample program ([allbutlast.hs](https://gist.github.com/tinkhaven/a31218239d7f2daebac1)). It has all the above solutions, a simple [quickcheck](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~rjmh/QuickCheck/manual.html) test and a benchmark using [criterion](http://www.serpentine.com/criterion/).

Prerequisites to run: QuickCheck and criterion

```
cabal update
cabal install QuickCheck
cabal install -j --disable-tests criterion
```

Execution

```
ghc -O2 --make allbutlast.hs
./allbutlast --output allbutlast.html
```

Sample report: [Criterion report for allbutlast](https://cdn.rawgit.com/tinkhaven/e7cb32c48e56001ef726/raw/c41164a39ac73c778adc05bbb9830849de716731/allbutlast-criterion-report.html)