# How to apply a function to a specific element of a list

Tags: haskell

How can I apply a function to only a single element of a list?
Any suggestion?

Example:

```
let list = [1,2,3,4,3,6]
    function x = x * 2
in ...
```

I want to apply `function` only to the first occurance of 3 and stop there.

Output:

```
List = [1,2,6,4,3,6] -- [1, 2, function 3, 4, 3, 6]
```

Comment: Any attempt on you side?

Comment: Furthermore what should happen if there are two threes in the list (or more)?

Comment: It's a list of Int!

Comment: and no, I have no ideia how to do it!

Comment: `map (\x -> if x == 3 then function x else x) List`

Comment: 4castle, changed the problem! Can u please get update?

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260828/do-we-need-a-close-reason-for-zero-effort-questions) for details on my close vote. "I didn't try" is a motivation problem, not a programming problem. Spend some time with a Haskell tutorial, and come back when you have a programming problem.

Comment: I tried the same solution 4castle did

Comment: Your solution does not seem to reflect your question. "Map a list 'till I find an input" is an interesting question, but your intended result seems to describe "find an input from a list and mutate that input" which is not.

Comment: Please try to implement it yourself, whether using `foldr` or explicit recursion, and then ask a more specific question about what you've attempted. Currently, it looks like you want someone else to do your work for you, which is not well suited for a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

you need to maintain some type of state to indicate the first instance of the value, since `map` will apply the function to all values.

Perhaps something like this

```
map (\(b,x) -> if (b) then f x else x) $ markFirst 3 [1,2,3,4,3,6]
```

and

```
markFirst :: a -> [a] -> [(Boolean,a)]
markFirst a [] = []
markFirst a (x:xs) | x==a = (True,x): zip (repeat False) xs
                   | otherwise = (False,x): markFirst a xs
```

I'm sure there is an easier way, but that's the best I came up with at this time on the day before Thanksgiving.

Here is another approach based on the comment below

```
> let leftap f (x,y) = f x ++ y

leftap (map (\x -> if(x==3) then f x else x)) $ splitAt 3 [1,2,3,4,3,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

To map or not to map, that is the question.

Better not to map.

Why? Because `map id == id` anyway, and you only want to map through *one* element, the first one found to be equal to the argument  given.

Thus, split the list in two, change the found element, and glue them all back together. Simple.

See: `span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`.

Write: `revappend (xs :: [a]) (ys :: [a])` == `append (reverse xs) ys`, only efficient.

Or fuse all the pieces together into one function. You can code it directly with manual recursion, or using `foldr`. Remember,

```
map f xs = foldr (\x r -> f x : r) [] xs

takeWhile p xs = foldr (\x r -> if p x then x : r else []) [] xs

takeUntil p xs = foldr (\x r -> if p x then [x] else x : r) [] xs

filter p xs = foldr (\x r -> if p x then x : r else r) [] xs

duplicate xs = foldr (\x r -> x : x : r) [] xs

mapFirstThat p f xs = -- ... your function
```

etc. Although, `foldr` won't be a direct fit, as you need the combining function of the `(\x xs r -> ...)` variety. That is known as paramorphism, and [can be faked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25853459/849891) by feeding `tails xs` to the `foldr`, instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a simple function which multiples a number by two:

```
times_two :: (Num a) => a -> a
times_two x = x * 2
```

Then simply search for the specified element in the list, and apply `times_two` to it. Something like this could work:

```
map_one_element :: (Eq a, Num a) => a -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]

-- base case
map_one_element _ _ [] = []

-- recursive case
map_one_element x f (y:ys)

    -- ff element is found, apply f to it and add rest of the list normally
    | x == y = f y : ys

    -- first occurence hasnt been found, keep recursing
    | otherwise = y : map_one_element x f ys
```

Which works as follows:

```
*Main> map_one_element 3 times_two [1,2,3,4,3,6]
[1,2,6,4,3,6]
```