# Haskell - using foldl or foldr instead of pattern matching for updating a list with a new value at a given index

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, fold

I have implemented a function (!!=) that given a list and a tuple containing an index in the list and a
new value, updates the given list with the new value at the given
index.

```
(!!=) :: [a] -> (Int,a) -> [a]
(!!=) xs (0, a) = a : tail xs
(!!=) [] (i, a) = error "Index not in the list"
(!!=) (x:xs) (i, a) = x : xs !!= (i-1, a)
```

Being a beginner with the concept of folding I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result using foldl or foldr instead?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Certainly it's possible with a fold, and may be a useful learning exercise. But once you've learned how to write this as a fold, instead write it in this simpler way: `(!!=) xs (i, a) = case splitAt i xs of { (pref, (_:post)) -> pref ++ [a] ++ post }` (where `splitAt` comes from Data.List)

Comment: Thanks a lot I didn't consider using splitAt before this is very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you the `foldl` version which is easier to understand I think and the easiest / most straight-forward version I can think of.

But please note that you should not use `foldl` (use `foldl'`: [https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl'](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl%27)) - nor should you use `++` like this (use `:` and reverse after) ;)

Anway this is the idea:

```hs
(!!=) xs (i, a) = snd $ foldl 
   (\(j, ys) x -> (j+1, if j == i then ys ++ [a] else ys ++ [x])) 
   (0, []) 
   xs
```

- as the *state/accumulator* for the fold I take a tuple of the current index and the accumulated result list (therefore the `snd` because I only want this in the end)
- then the folding function just have to look if we are at the index and exchange the element - returning the next index and the new accumulated list

---

as an exercise you can try to:

- use `:` instead of `++` and a `reverse`
- rewrite as `foldr`
- look at [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) and rewrite this using this (`zipWith (...) [0..] xs`) instead of the *fold* (this is similar to using a *map* with index

Answer (score 0):

Neither `foldl` nor `foldr` can do this particular job *efficiently* (unless you "cheat" by pattern matching on the list as you fold over it), though `foldr` can do it a bit less badly. No, what you really need is a different style of fold, sometimes called `para`:

```hs
para :: (a -> [a] -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
para _f n [] = n
para f n (a : as) = f a as (para f n as)
```

`para` is very similar to `foldr`. Each of them takes a combining function and, for each element, passes the combining function that element and the result of folding up the rest of the list. But `para` adds something extra: it also passes in the rest of the list! So there's no need to reconstruct the tail of the list once you've reached the replacement point.

But ... how do you count from the beginning with `foldr` or `para`? That brings in a classic trick, sometimes called a "higher-order fold". Instead of `para go stop xs` producing a *list*, it's going to produce a *function* that takes the insertion position as an argument.

```hs
(!!=) :: [a] -> (Int, a) -> [a]
xs0 !!= (i0, new) = para go stop xs0 i0
  where
    -- If the list is empty, then no matter what index
    -- you seek, it's not there.
    stop = \_ -> error "Index not in the list"

    -- We produce a function that takes an index. If the
    -- index is 0, we combine the new element with "the rest of the list".
    -- Otherwise we apply the function we get from folding up the rest of
    -- the list to the predecessor of the index, and tack on the current
    -- element.
    go x xs r = \i -> case i of
      0 -> new : xs
      _ -> x : r (i - 1)
```

---

Note that `para` is easily powerful enough to implement `foldr`:

```
foldr c = para (\a _ b -> c a b)
```

What's perhaps less obvious is that `foldr` can implement a (very inefficient version of) `para`:

```
para f n = snd . foldr go ([], n)
  where
    go x ~(xs, r) = (x : xs, f x xs r)
```

---

Lest you get the wrong idea and think that `para` is "better than" `foldr`, know that when its extra power *isn't* needed, `foldr` is simpler to use and will very often be compiled to more efficient code.

Comment: I know we had this conversation before, but I still don't understand and don't remember now why one should be a "classic trick", and the other, "cheating". Even if it fuses badly, say, it's still not "cheating"? A right fold with a left-to-right state passing is always going to need the extra argument (or two) to pass the state in, and whether I update that state with a `(+1)` or an unconditional (and correct by construction) `tail`, what's the diff really? So using this to emulate a paramorphism should be fine, but if not, there's always `tails` to fold over. now _that_ cld be "cheating". :)

Comment: @WillNess, I'm often opinionated. I remember this cheat being used for one library function somewhere—don't remember what. I'm not the biggest fan of pattern matching twice on the same thing in general, though I did it in [`Data.Biapplicative.traverseBia`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-5.5.7/docs/Data-Biapplicative.html#v:traverseBia) to avoid `unsafeCoerce`.

Comment: OK, that's something. thanks! :) BTW if you remember, in the less scrupulous Common Lisp they do have this thing called `maplist` which _is_ `map` on `tails` (and the regular `map` they call `mapcar`).

Comment: @WillNess, my only exposure to CL was looking at a manual one time. It was a bit traumatizing.

Comment: I can relate. :) But I meant maybe you remembered it from that previous convo, where I also mentioned that [pretend-paramorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25853459/849891) that uses that technique (I think I did).